# file description updated with Google Apps Script is not retrieved

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

I update the description associated with a File in Drive using the file.setDescription(newDescription) method, within e script project, published as a web app.

If a subsequent execution of the same script reads again the description of the same file (getDescription method) the value returned is the "old" description (befor the update).
If I immediately look at the details of the file from the Drive page, I see the updated description.

Only after a variable time (from 5 to 30 minutes) the script execution retrieves the updated description (without any other intervention).

It seems that the GAS engine (I'm using V8, but this behavior started with th previous Rhino engine) keeps internally a cache of the last files processed, and ignores the updates, until the cache expires.

Do you know a way to circumvent this?

Thanks

As an example:

```
  while (files.hasNext() ) {
    var file = files.next();
    var fdes = file.getDescription(); // 'old' description was 'Hello World'
    .....
    var newdes = 'Good evening world';
    file.setDescription(newdes);
   }
```

After the loop, if I look at the file description using the drive web interface, I see the updated description: 'Good evening world'.
If a execute again the loop, fdes variable is 'Hello world'.
After a 5min to 1hr interval, the getDescription method retrieves the updated description

Comment: Please add a [mcve]

Comment: Hi there @MassimoColetti ! After studying your example I couldn't replicate the problematic behaviour. To better research the issue, could you please share a minimal example that reproduces the error without further additions?

Comment: Hi, sorry for the delay, but we have spent a lot of time investigating the problem.
To reproduce the behavior the code fragment is enough.
1. create a folder with two/three files (pdf is ok)
2. set the description of one file with any string
3. run the loop, and force the description to a new value
4. look at the file details using the drive web interface: you will see the updated description
5. run the loop again, and place a breakpoint after the assignment of fdes variable
Expected result: the new description previously updated
Noticed result: the original description

Comment: After a delay of 10/20 (or more) minutes, the issue disappear: the loop retrieves the updated description.
We have tested with different PC/browsers, and also performing the second loop in debugging on a different PC, but the behavior is the same.
It seems that the Script engine caches somewhere the files.next results, and the cache is not updated by the .setDescription method, but this is only guesswork. I wasn't able to find any documentation.